# How can I read the two value down a child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my database reference:

[image]

I want to read the two key's value(reminddate and title) and show on the `listview`.How can I do it?

Metodolist.java

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  final DatabaseReference hom = database.getReference("Student").child(student_id).child("event");
  listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);
  final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1);
  listview.setAdapter(adapter);

  hom.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot event : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
                                        Event = event.getValue().toString();
                                        Log.e("Metodolist",Event);
                                        adapter.add(Event);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }

                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
  Log.e("MeTo list","Pass1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how can be done:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference eventRef = rootRef.child("Student").child(student_id).child("event");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String reminddate = ds.child("reminddate").getValue(String.class);
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", reminddate + " / " + title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
eventRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
22-02-18 / A
23-02-18 / B
```

Comment: Thanks,and how can i put back to the `listview`?

Comment: I the same way you do. Have you tried it? Do you have an error?

Comment: Yes,I've try but It put the two data(title and reminddate) apart. I want 1 child to be  1 listview column, like the title to be the Item 1 and the reminddate to be the sub Item 1

Comment: Hi,there thanks for the help. I've posted another question for creating new adapter, cuz I am new in this field.